# How to have a sealed constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, sealed

I have a baseclass which has public contructors.

The baseclass is not sealed and is not abstract.

There is one constructor which I desire to be sealed. Is this possible?

My current attempt results in syntax error saying the constructor cannot be sealed.

```
public sealed MyBase(string someParam)
```

**Additional:**

I wish to be able to instantiate the base class directly and have access to the sealed constructor. Derived classes cannot use that constructor via the derived constructors.
E.g.

```
public MyDerived() : base(string cant_access_my_sealed_constructor)
```

Comment: What do you mean? Constructors are not inherited, and they are not virtual. How could one of them be `sealed`?

Comment: I only said `The baseclass is not sealed and is not abstract.`

Comment: Any comment on the down vote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that. If the constructor is `public`, you can call it from constructors of derived classes. But you can do something close – you can have a `private` constructor and a `public static` method that calls it:

```
class MyBase
{
    private MyBase(string someParam)
    {
        // some code
    }

    public static MyBase Create(string someParam)
    {
        return new MyBase(someParam);
    }

    protected MyBase() // or some other protected or public constructor
    { }
}

class MyDerived : MyBase
{
    public MyDerived()
        : base("foo") // won't compile, as requested
    { }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have any constructors accessible to child classes, you might as well just make your class `sealed`.

Comment: This is a very good answer and the sort of workaround i was looking for. thanks!

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, right, but from the question I assumed there is at least one other constructor usable from derived classes. I have clarified the code in my answer.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. +1

Answer (score 6):

All constructors are "sealed" in that they cannot be "overridden." They can only be called from the constructor in a child class.

If you are hoping to prevent child classes from having a constructor with the same signature, that cannot be done.

Based on the additional information you added to the post, it sounds like what you want to do is make your constructor private, as Kyle suggested. This will prevent the child class from calling the constructor, but it won't prevent it from taking the same types of arguments:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Foo(string s){
    }
    // Allowed
    public Foo() : this("hello") {
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    // Allowed
    public Bar(string s) : base(){
    }
    // Not allowed
    public Bar(string s) : base(s){
    }
}
```

Comment: @Valamas: I added a little more information based on your updated question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent the constructor from being called by inherited classes, just mark it private.

Constructors aren't inherited by a child class, you have to explicitly call a base constructor if desired.

This code will call the base class' no-parameter constuctor when an instance of the child class is instantiated.  Without it, the base class' constructor won't be called when creating a new instance of the child class.

```
public class A
{
    public A() 
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B() 
        : base() 
    {
    }
}
```